# Upload script doesn't register the file type its meant to upload

Tags: php, upload

My upload script doesn't seem to even upload the file type it was designed for.
Here's the script:

```
<?php

$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");

$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

The script always seems to list the files as "invalid file" no matter what I change.
Instead, I want it to upload to a certain file in the same directory as the uploader.

Comment: try using http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php to identify the file type

Comment: i would, but most PHP is to confusing for me, im still a beginner.

Comment: Okay in which case I would really recommend trying to learn the basics and understand all the PHP code you are using. Copying and pasting scripts from the internet will get you into trouble

Answer (score 1):

Use more descriptive errors. If necessary, change the workflow.

For example:

```
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$mimes       = array('image/gif','image/jpeg','image/png','image/pjpeg');
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));

function check_errors()
{
    if (!in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $mimes))
        return "Invalid MIME type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"];
    if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] >= 20000)
        return "File too long: size=" . $_FILES["file"]["size"];
    if (!in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
        return "Extension not allowed: '".$extension."'";
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        return "Return code " . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
    return "OK";
}

if ('OK' == ($reason = check_errors()))
{
    // your code
}
else
{
    echo "ERROR: $reason";
}
```